# Get height of a parent div

Tags: jquery

```
  <div class='contain'>
     <a href="#">
        <div id="s1" class="sub" onclick="hello('1')">dasdad</div>
     </a>
  </div>
 <div class='contain'>
     <a href="#">
        <div id="s2" class="sub" onclick="hello('2')">dasdad</div>
     </a>
  </div>
```

From the above how can I get the height of the parent contain div when div sub is clicked in jquery.

Tried using `$('#s1').parent().height();`.

### CSS

```
   .contain{margin:auto;width:auto; height:auto;}
   .sub{width:160px;min-height: 173px;}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) just using parent will only get one level up the `<a>` element, so you must either use parent() twice or use closest()

```
$('#s1').closest('.contain').height();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/3Ykk9/)

Comment: I am getting 0 using this

Comment: I am using an onclick event. In css the height of contain div is set to auto. So that it extends according to the size of inner divs. So I need to get the size of contain for total size.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('.sub').closest('.contain').height();
```

Use this JS

```
$('.sub').click(function(e){
    alert($(this).closest('.contain').height())
});
```

Comment: I am getting 0 using this

Answer (score 0):

you have anchor as the parent of `#s1`  . so you need to use `parent().parent()`

try like this:

```
$('#s1').parent().parent('div.contain').height();
```

if you want to use class selector then try like this:

```
$('.sub').parent().parent('div.contain').height();
```

<kbd>[fiddle demo using id](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/103/)</kbd><kbd>[demo using class](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/105/)</kbd>

Comment: @Developer: did you try this?

Comment: Yeah I am getting 0 using this

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I concur with Anton's original answer,

I think a more complete example incorporating your original code would be beneficial.

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/AjqJr/2/

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.hello = function (someNumber) {
        // Do something here
        console.log(someNumber);
    }

    $('.sub').on('click', function () {
        alert($(this).closest('.contain').height());
    });
});
```